# Table cache hit rate: 0%

Tags: mysql, cache

I have an AWS RDS Mysql Server with Table cache hit rate's problem. If I do a query on phpmyadmin (also simple query) always do it without cache.

Here the mysqltuner log:

```
MySQLTuner 1.6.12 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Performing tests on xxxxxxxxxx
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: xxxx
Please enter your MySQL administrative password:
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[--] Assuming 15000 MB of physical memory
[!!] Assuming 0 MB of swap space (use --forceswap to specify)
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.27-log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 231G (Tables: 5052)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2G (Tables: 339)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 86

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[!!] User 'mysql.sys@localhost' has no password set.
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 44d 18h 57m 56s (658M q [170.285 qps], 10M conn, TX: 482G, RX: 354G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 52% / 48%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 14.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 13.5G
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
[--] Other process memory: 273.4M
[--] Total buffers: 13.3G global + 2.2M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 13.4G (91.49% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 13.5G (92.27% of installed RAM)
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 1% (6M/658M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 48% (48/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.52%  (56490/10863413)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (124K temp sorts / 20M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 265811
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 3% (413K on disk / 12M total)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (6K open / 3M opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 12% (8K/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 98% (629M immediate / 636M locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 99.56% ( 3252959 Memory / 3267284 Total)

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Key buffer used: 100.0% (268M used / 268M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/73.1G
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 97.3% (41B cached / 1B reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 88.7% (5B cached / 621M writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 11.1G/2.9G
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 11
[OK] InnoDB Used buffer: 98.45% (713650 used/ 724922 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (60609315410 hits/ 60609364241 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 99.67% (509380571 hits/ 511044352 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1663781 writes)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: 
    Beware that open_files_limit (65535) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 6396)
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 1.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_open_cache (> 6396)
```

I have some query that are slow query logged because don't use index (but not at all).

Can someone explain how resolve this hits rate problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some of what MySQLTuner says is bogus.  Here are the things that seem bad:

You are using MyISAM instead of InnoDB; this is generally sub-optimal.

Fragmented tables -- bogus.  There may be some MyISAM tables that could use `OPTIMIZE`, but probably not.

3GB of InnoDB tables, yet the buffer_pool is much bigger.  Lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 3500M and the instances to 3.

You have lots of MyISAM indexes, yet a small key_cache.  Increase `key_buffer_size` to 3G.

Lower `long_query_time` to 1, run for awhile, then use pt-query-digest to find the worst couple of queries.  Fix them.  (This will deal with several of the "!!" comments - joins, disk tmp tables, write key, etc.)

How long was mysqld up when you ran this script?  A 1% miss rate for `table_open_cache` is not that bad, but maybe the `Opened_tables / Uptime` is bad.  I consider over 2/sec to be bad.

If you would like a different analysis, post `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and size of RAM.  (Probably need post.it because of size.)